# Why is there no [trailing-newlines] tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags

In Rust programming language this seems like a fixed idiom. So why doesn't this exist on Stack Overflow? I could not create it either.

I'm wondering since I was searching for it and did not find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761227/how-to-make-intellij-idea-insert-a-new-line-at-every-end-of-file).

Comment: Seems rather... specialised?

Comment: What kind of questions would be asked in such a tag?

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a tag because you don't have the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) yet, that comes at 1500 reputation. It's a lot higher on Stack Overflow than on other Stack Exchange sites, because we have seen a lot of awful tags in the past.

Also, you don't create tags because you just can, you do it with a purpose. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

Not being able to find a specific question is not a strong case. The question you refer to could be retagged with [newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newline), and searching for your IDE and [newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newline) would then give you the question you're looking for.